# Publish Web API controllers in separate files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem with publishing Web API in Visual Studio.

In VS, when I publish the Web API, it is published as dll's, and when we have several controllers it is going to aggregate those into one dll.

But I have project that can have different controllers, like:

```
Android.cs
CoWorker.cs
TelegramBot.cs
```

and when I publish the project, I would like to publish the controllers in separated DLL's, because I should have update the controllers continuously and when I have an error in a specific controller, I can't publish another.

Please help!

Comment: once the project is compiled, you have to re-compile and publish the whole project if you make changes. This is normal. You don't need to worry about this.

Comment: no my problem accurred when for example i change android.cs and Coworker.cs but i should publish just Coworker.cs

Comment: yes you have to publish everything again, like I just mentioned. The "Publish" action compiles all your code into binary, machine-friendly code inside one or more DLLs (usually one per C# project / reference in your solution). You don't publish the C# files to the server directly. If you change something in the C# you have to re-build your project (this creates the DLLs based on your source code) and re-publish (this copies them to the server). (Without re-building, you cannot even use the changes locally when you run in debug mode).

Comment: You can't publish only one part of the code. If you changed 2 things but only want to publish one of them, this is a problem of project management, not publishing. You'd have to save your unwanted changes elsewhere (e.g. in a branch or shelveset in your source control system, perhaps), revert them in your project and then publish. Or plan your work more, and don't make the changes until you've published the previous changes.

Comment: If you want separate DLL's - one per controller - you have to have **a separate project** for each controller

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for will not happen on its own. If you want a plug and play like architecture where you can just publish only a module without re-publishing the whole solution.

To achieve this you need to move your controller(s)/module as a separate project (separate library). One of the useful configuration feature of `ASP.NET Web API` is that it allows you to define about the assemblies into which it will look to discover your controller types.

This is very useful if you have external assemblies and are not part of the Web API project.

You can implement interface `System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.IAssembliesResolver` `GetAssemblies()` or even can extend the `DefaultAssembliesResolver` as following.

```
public class CustomAssembliesResolver : DefaultAssembliesResolver
{
   public override ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
   {
       //Your implementation here 
   }
}
```

You can find more details on this on following link.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.dispatcher.iassembliesresolver(v=vs.118).aspx)

[Sample](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a MICRO-SERVICE architecture ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/data-driven-crud-microservice

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers

you can use .NET full framework

or the new .NET Core (it depends on what you have to do)